# jQuery Click event doesn't fire on parent div that has same size as descendent img?

Tags: jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

The HTML code is as below (the `img` fits to the `div` parent):

```
<div id='draggable_task' style='display: inline-block; position: relative; overflow: hidden'>
    <img src='../Content/BPMN Icons/Big Icons/BigTask.png' />
    <p style='position: absolute; top: 20%; left:20%;'>Task name</p>
</div>
```

The JavaScript code is as below (`DrawArea` is the top container):

```
$("#DrawArea").on("click", function (e) {
    alert(e.target.nodeName);
});
```

When I click on `div` it displays type = `img`.

Comment: The click event was fired on the `img` element and it bubbled up the DOM until it was caught by the event handler on your `#DrawArea` element. What is the problem you're having?

Comment: There is no `NodeType` property AFAIK, i guess you mean `nodeType` but that returns a number, so...? And waht if you click on `<p>`?

Comment: i want the click event to be fired on div ('parent of img')

Comment: See my answer below.  The image is taking up all the space, so any container elements are not going to be easy to click without heavy padding, and even then you would have to click just outside the image.

Comment: One soultion is to set following CSS rule  `#draggable_task * {pointer-events: none;}` see browsers support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events  That's said, i still don't understand why you don't bind click event on DIV `#draggable_task`??? Or use `$(e.target).closest('div')`. Anyway, you'd have better to explain clearly what you are looking for?!

Comment: i want the iamge to fit the parent div and when clicked i want to get the div id to display some modal form. i think the solution is to fire click event on image and get the parent id (div) by this code $(e.target).closest('div').i think this is the only solution

Comment: i want the iamge to fit the parent div and when clicked i want to get the div id to display some modal form. i think the solution is to fire click event on image and get the parent id (div) by this code $(e.target).closest('div').i think this is the only solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited per your comments...try the snippet below (CSS added just to show the different elements)

```js
$("#DrawArea").on("click", function (e) {
    alert($(e.target).closest('div').attr('id'));
});
```

```css
#DrawArea{
    background:#0000cc;
}
#draggable_task{
    background:#cc0000;
}
p{
    background:#00cc00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="DrawArea">

<div id='draggable_task' style='display:inline-block;position: relative;overflow: hidden'>
    <img src='http://www.placehold.it/350x150'/>
     <p style='position: absolute; top: 20%; left:20%;'>Task name</p>
 </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: i want the iamge to fit the parent div and when clicked i want to get the div id to display some modal form. i think the solution is to fire click event on image and get the parent id (div) by this code $(e.target).closest('div').i think this is the only solution

Comment: @Deli in that case, yes, that is the way to go. I edited my answer to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your intentions with this are.  Maybe you do in fact need a literal img tag.

You have a couple of alternatives.  Leaving the JS as-is, you could set the image to be a background image.  You can still scale it using css.  Ask if unsure about that and I can show you.

Also, you could have the .on() fire on the image instead of the parent of the image.

EDIT: The reason this is happening is because the image is setting the real-estate.  I assume the unseen (in your example) parent has no padding, so it is unclickable in most cases, and you'd click the image instead of the parent in nearly all scenarios.

Comment: thanks i will test your solution and make the image in the background of the div